# Эффект с музыкой JS

Tags: javascript

Нужна помощь! Есть сайт - https://unitk.ai/
Как добиться таких же эффектов с музыкой с помощью JS? Чтобы, когда мышка выходила за пределы сайта, звук имел такой же эффект как и на сайте по ссылке (также плавное потухание музыки при клике (плавное выключение))

Comment: вставляете тэг `audio` с `visibility: hidden` и что то типа `autoplay`. Легко гуглится

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: @Meth0d Тэг audio более не поддерживает autoplay! Для запуска `<audio src="test.mp3">` можно запустить автоматический только после user interraction. Например `document.body("click", ev => myAudio.play());`

Comment: @EugeneX спасибо. наверное именно поэтому сайт просит сначала кликнуть в произвольном месте

Comment: @Meth0d Тут вопрос не про то, как вставить звук, а как его изменять при выходе за границы window.

Comment: Но на том сайте через один клик то включается, то плавно выключается музыка, а при выходе за границы window ничего не происходит. Так как быть?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Этот ответ является доработкой предыдущего в плане того, что теперь когда курсор выходит за пределы страницы, частотная характеристика музыки плавно меняется в сторону выделения низких частот и восстанавливается после возвращения курсора на страницу:

```
<style>
#paused{
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -50px;
    bottom: 15px;
    color: #811;
    width: 100px;
    text-align: center;
}
</style>    
<div id=paused>PAUSED</div>
<script>
let myinterval;
let audio = new Audio("sound.mp3");
let api = false;
document.onclick = () => {
    if (!api){
        api = true;
        let a = new AudioContext();
        pt = [a.createMediaElementSource(audio), a.createBiquadFilter(), a.destination];
        pt[1].frequency.value = 18000;
        pt[1].Q.value = 15;
        pt[1].type = "lowpass";
        for (let i = 0; i < 2; i ++) pt[i].connect(pt[i + 1]);
    }
    if (audio.paused){
        audio.play();
        paused.hidden = true;
    } else {
        audio.pause();
        paused.hidden = false;
    }
}
document.onmouseover = () => {
    if (!audio.paused){
        clearInterval(myinterval);
        myinterval = setInterval(function(){
            pt[1].frequency.value *= 1.2;
            if (pt[1].frequency.value >= 18000){
                clearInterval(myinterval);
            }
        }, 100);
    }
}
document.onmouseleave = () => {
    if (!audio.paused){
        clearInterval(myinterval);
        pt[1].frequency.value = 8000;
        myinterval = setInterval(function(){
            pt[1].frequency.value /= 1.05;
            if (pt[1].frequency.value <= 500) clearInterval(myinterval);
        }, 100);
    }
}
</script>
```

Аудиофайл должен находиться в пределах того же самого домена, что и HTML-документ.

Comment: спасибо вам большое! Этот эффект в дальнейшем не будет оставаться при паузе по самому сайту? Просто будет исчезать музыка, я правильно понимаю?

Comment: ещё если знаете, то подскажите, пожалуйста, когда только нижние частоты у меня аудио начинает скрипеть как-то... дело в аудио или в моём ноутбуке?

Comment: Может программно зашкаливает уровень, попробуйте уменьшить громкость: `audio.volume = 0.7`

Comment: Это можно вставить между второй и третьей строками. По паузе будет приостанавливаться воспроизведение.

Comment: не очень поняла касательно вставить между второй и третьей строками, вставила вроде как, но не вышло ничего

Comment: Попробуйте 0.5, должно становиться тише. Или уменьшить резонанс - в 13 строке поменять `pt[1].Q.value = 10;`

Comment: спасибо! С volume помогло, больше ничего не скрипит. С паузой не разобралась, можете подсказать, пожалуйста, как её сделать?

Comment: Я уже сделал функционал паузы, изменил второй ответ. Теперь после нажатия на паузу наблюдается эффект реверберации, как на упомянутом сайте.

Comment: спасибо вам большое! А можно от эффекта реверберации избавиться как-нибудь, пожалуйста?... Просто чтобы музыка останавливалась:)

Comment: Убрал реверберацию. (`ломать - не строить :)`)

Comment: и ещё раз и ещё много раз большое спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Этот пример предусматривает оба случая:

```js
let myinterval;
let audio = new Audio("http://tolmatux.strana.de/audio/razminka.mp3");
let isplay = false;
let ispause = true;
document.onmouseover = () => {
  if (ispause == false) play();
}
document.onmouseleave = () => {
  if (isplay) pause();
}
document.onclick = () => {
  if (isplay) {
    ispause = true;
    pause();
  } else {
    ispause = false;
    play();
  }
}

function play() {
  isplay = true;
  paused.style.display = "none";
  clearInterval(myinterval);
  audio.volume = 1;
  audio.play();
}

function pause() {
  if (isplay) {
    isplay = false;
    paused.style.display = "block";
    myinterval = setInterval(function() {
      audio.volume -= 0.03;
      if (audio.volume <= 0.03) {
        clearInterval(myinterval);
        audio.pause();
      }
    }, 100);
  }
}
```

```css
#paused {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -50px;
  bottom: 15px;
  color: #811;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id=paused>PAUSED</div>
```

Comment: Без варианта уменьшения громкости музыки, когда выходишь мышкой за пределы сайта? И есть ли возможность с плавным потухание музыки при клике на выключение?

Comment: Это всё можно сделать. На том сайте используют не обычное уменьшение громкости, а довольно сложные эффекты, создаваемые с помощью **WebAudio Api**. А уменьшение громкости сейчас добавлю (дорботаю ответ)

Comment: Я изменил ответ.

Comment: очень круто! Спасибо больше! А можно как-то сделать так, чтобы когда ставишь на паузу, выходишь за пределы сайта мышкой и возвращаешься обратно, музыка не начинала играть и не уходила из состояния паузы, а так и оставалась на паузе? И добавить при стопе надпись PAUSED снизу. У меня были попытки в добавлением текста через JS, но не получалось задать ему нужный css

Comment: можно ещё спросить о кое чём? возможно может изменение частот музыки, когда выходишь за пределы сайта будут низкие частоты у аудио и возвращение уже нормальных частот, когда курсор вновь на сайте?

Comment: Да, всё это можно. Частоты мы сделаем с помощью WebAudio Api.

Comment: Я исправил ответ, учитывая пока пожелание о невыхождении из состояния паузы и появление надписи PAUSED. Для задания CSS лучше всего использовать теги **style** а появление/исчезновение сделал с помощью JS управляя только одним стилем **display**.

Чуть позже сделаю изменение частот. (наверно создам второй ответ)

Comment: большое человеческое спасибо! Вы очень мне помогаете!

Comment: здравствуйте! У вас получилось сделать эффект с музыкой через WebAudio Api?

Comment: Здравствуйте! Да, получилось. Я создал второй ответ.